# How to find index of li which doesn't have id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Hi I am creating tabs in JSP using twitter bootstrap.

```
<ul>
    <li id="first"><a href="#datacollector" target="main"data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
    <li><a href="#dataTab" data-toggle="tab">Transport</a></li>
    <li><a href="#datamap" data-toggle="tab">Data Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="#schedule" data-toggle="tab">Schedule</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now I have given id for first `LI` but dynamically I will be giving id to `LI`.

How to find the index of `LI` which does not have id? If the second one has no id, it should find the index of that LI only and should not check for remaining `LI` How can I get that?

Comment: why are you not creating Id for all li... dynamicaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `:not .first()` and `.index()`:

```
var idx = $('li:not([id])').first().index();
console.log(idx);
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2sg76/)

This will get you the index of first li which doesn't have an id.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [Siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/). You could also get a reference to the [Parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a function for this:

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

NB: `.index()` returns a zero-based index.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AdK3s/) is a working jsfiddle

To only target li's without an id, make use of the `:not()` selector and `[id]` attribute selector:

```
$('li:not([id])').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdK3s/1/)

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - .index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: But that was not my problem

Comment: What was your problem? I could only understand that you wanted to find the index

Comment: but this when I click on a tab it is alerting the index. I want the index of `LI` which doesn't has Id

Comment: I just used the click to show that `.index()` is working. What exactly do you want to do with the index, I don't know?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').each(function(index){

            $(this).addClass('index-'+index);

        });
```

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/superbshivam/HqpSF/

Answer (score 0):

Very quick and dirty approach, but it should get you started on what you need.

```
var indexWithoutId = -1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    findIndexWithoutId();
    console.log("without id: " + indexWithoutId);
});

function findIndexWithoutId() {
    $("li").each(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        if (typeof(id) === "undefined") {
            indexWithoutId = index;
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

[Working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pcaldredbann/Gghxz/)